# SASS/SCSS remove hyphen(-) if map has key called null?

Tags: css, sass

I want to remove **hyphen(-)** if map **$spacers** has key called **null**.
means it return only the **className** is this case it called **m** without **hyphen(-)**.

```
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: 1px,
  2: 2px,
  null: 3px,
  4: 4px,
  8: 8px
) !default;

@each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m) {
   @each $size, $length in $spacers {
      .#{$abbrev}-#{$size} {
         #{$prop}: $length !important;
      }
   }
}
```

**the result that I get after compiling :**

```
.m-0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.m-1 {
  margin: 1px !important;
}

.m-2 {
  margin: 2px !important;
}

// hyphen(-) shouldn't be here
.m- {
  margin: 3px !important;
}

.m-4 {
  margin: 4px !important;
}

.m-8 {
  margin: 8px !important;
}
```

Comment: Use `@if` and `@else`.

Comment: How can I do if statement inside Hyphen (-)

Comment: `.#{$abbrev}-#{$size} {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@if` and `@else`.

```
@each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m) {
    @each $size, $length in $spacers {
        @if $size {
            .#{$abbrev}-#{$size} {
                #{$prop}: $length !important;
            }
        } @else {
            .#{$abbrev} {
                #{$prop}: $length !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use a ternary operator and just write: `.#{if($size, $abbrev + "-" + $size, $abbrev)}`